# Detect and handle Dialog/Alert pop up being triggered from remote Powershell session

Tags: powershell

I've written some scripts to perform a set of remote deployments. I do this by executing a script locally, which does an `Invoke-Command` to trigger a script to run on the remote server. This deploys a Windows Service with supplied credentials.

This all works great for the most part, and saves us (me) a whole load of time. However, I occasionally hit an issue which manifests itself with a Prompt (alert/dialog box etc) that I cannot seem to get around.

If I log onto the remote machine and run the script, I can see the prompt appear. It says something along the lines of "This action cannot be completed because the file is open in another process". The actual issue itself is probably race condition related, as I can get around it just by dismissing the prompt, but the problem is that I cannot "get the alert" remotely - the script at my end just hangs.

What I'd really like to do is handle the Alert, regardless of what it says and what the options are, I'd like to either "bring it back" to the remote end so to speak, or at least have some sort of notification that it's blocking the operation with some way to dismiss it.

Here's an example of it:

[image: Alert/Prompt]

**EDIT:**

We have two machines (A), and (B). (A) is my machine, (B) is the remote server.
On (A), I have a script [let's call it `RemoteExecute.ps1`], which contains something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock { c:\updates\Deploy.ps1 }
```

`C:\updates` is a location on (B), and `Deploy.ps1` is a script in that location. `Deploy.ps1` is the script which triggers the Alert on (B). If I log onto (B) via Remote Desktop and execute `Deploy.ps1` locally on that machine, it gives me the Alert on screen.

However, when I run this script remotely from (A), via the `RemoteExecute.ps1` script, I don't see the Alert that's generated on (B) and I have no way of even knowing that an Alert is blocking things. My my end on (A) all I see is the RemoteExecute script hanging indefinitely.

How can I detect that there's an Alert waiting to be dismissed on (B)?

**EDIT 2:**

```
#Extract from Deploy script:
Write-Host 'Deploying files ...'
if (!(Test-Path $targetpath)) { 
    mkdir $targetpath
}
Expand-ZIPFile "$releasepath\$ExeName.zip" $targetpath
Write-Host 'Files deployed'
```

...

```
#Function from another file:
function Expand-ZIPFile($file, $destination)
{
   $shell = new-object -com shell.application
   $zip = $shell.NameSpace($file)
   $destFolder = $shell.Namespace($destination)

   if (!(test-path $file)) { throw "$file does not exist" }   

    foreach($item in $zip.items())
    {
        $shell.Namespace($destination).copyhere($item, 0x14)
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show the code? As I am still not sure what are you trying to do.

Comment: PowerShell code should normally not pop up dialog boxes. Can you show the relevant code from `deploy.ps1`?